# how to operate $concat use spring mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

i am using spring-data-mongodb(version is 1.8.1.release) to operate my mongodb,
but i encounter a problem.
i want to use aggregate to projection a new field,which use #concat to join two field. like this:

```
{
"$project":{
    "idai" : {
        "$concat": [
        {"$substr":["$channel_id",0,-1]},
        "-",
        {"$substr":["$no_ai",0,-1]}
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

and the below code is my java code

```
AggregationResults<QualifyHourData> results = mongoOps.aggregate(newAggregation(HisAiInfo.class, 
            match(where("date").gte(startTime.toDate()).lt(endTime.toDate())),
            project("date","zset").andExpression("$channelId + [0] + $noAi",CHAR_CHANNELID_NOAI).as("idai"),
            ...
            ), QualifyHourData.class);
```

when it run,the log is:

```
{ 
  "aggregate" : "last" , 
  "pipeline" : [ 
    { "$match" : { "date" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2015-11-30T16:00:00.000Z"} , "$lt" : { "$date" : "2015-12-31T16:00:00.000Z"}}}},
    { "$project" : { "date" : 1 , "zset" : 1 , "idai" : { "$add" : [ "$channel_id" , "_" , "$no_ai"]}}} , ...
  ]
}
```

look,this is not my expired.
please help!!!

Comment: `$concat` can be used like this `.andExpression("concat(name, 'foo-bar')").`

Comment: @ChristophStrobl thank you for your help,i resloved my question use your suggestion

Answer (score 5):

Just summarized the solution to help others having the same issue.

You can concatenate the values using "andExpression" function in org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ProjectionOperation class.

**Example:-**

```
ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation.project("year", "initial").andExpression("concat(year,'-', initial)").as("yearAndInitial");
```

Answer (score 2):

As of [Spring Data MongoDB 2.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.supported-aggregation-operations) you can use `StringUtils.Concat`:

```
project("_id",)
    .and("firstName")
    .concat(" ", fields("lastName"))
    .as("fullName"),
```